# CSS solution for removing border from ul height without using calc()

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation's top bar component and I've added a 1px and 3px (top,bottom) border to the nav tag. I'm encountering height issues because the ul menu inside is set to 100% height.

What would be the most efficient way to subtract the 4px height?

I want to avoid CSS calc() for compatibility reasons, but I'm only looking for IE8+ compatibility. I saw a comment in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866301/is-there-a-cross-browser-solution-to-height-calc100-70px) that referenced using `display: table` which I've tried to apply without success.

CSS added to default nav:

```
nav { 
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  @include box-shadow(0 0 5px 0 hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2));
}
```

UL Height CSS Excerpt:

```
  .top-bar-section ul {
    width: auto;
    height: auto !important;
    display: inline;
  }
```

Section HTML excerpt inside nav tag:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
    </ul>

    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CASE STUDIES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

Comment: Try using `box-sizing: border-box;`. This makes border and padding part of the given width.

Comment: @Harry That's the answer right there. Just post it as such. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` on the element that has the border. This makes `border` and `padding` part of the given `height` and `width`.

Default value for `box-sizing` is `content-box`. In that case the actual rendered `height` of an element is the given height + padding + border.

You can find more details about `box-sizing` in this [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

**EDIT:** Modified `width` to `height` as the question is about `height`.

Comment: Thank you! Turned out to be an `overflow:visible` issue, but your answer is correct and it helped me to find the problem since the box-sizing was set correctly.